# WebStorm see TypeScript server logs

Tags: typescript, webstorm

In VSCode I can go into 'OUTPUT' and see logs of all internal tasks that VSCode is running for me, for example a TypeScript server:

[image]

I need to see the logs of the TypeScript server in WebStorm because I need to debug weird compilation behavior.

How can I reveal all tasks and servers and their logs WebStorm is running for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enable debug logging for `#com.intellij.lang.javascript.service.JSLanguageServiceQueue:trace` in **Help | Debug log settings** and then inspect the idea.log.* files (**Help > Show Log in ...**) as well as the `.log` files created in your project folder while working with your app

Comment: Not that comfortable, but it will do

Comment: Very useful! This helped me debug a Typescript plugin in an editor other than VSCode (JetBrains / WebStorm). Apparently VSCode has an easier way to view this sort of thing.

Comment: This seems to show the trace of what webstorm send and receive, but not the **actual** tsserver logs.

Answer (score 2):

*The accepted answer does not give the **actual** tsserver logs AFAICS, but rather a trace of what webstorm send and receive to the server (which is useful in itself).*

Turning on logging is done using an [environment variable](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-%28tsserver%29#logging):

```
$ export TSS_LOG="-level verbose -file /tmp/webstorm-tsserver.log"
$ webstorm
```

---

Details: (Webstorm version: 2022.1.3 (linux))

Webstorm overrides `TSS_LOG` to `-level verbose` when `#com.intellij.lang.javascript.service.JSLanguageServiceQueue:trace` is set. In that case the logs are written to `$PROJECT_ROOT/.log$PID`

Ref: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56446/Not-possible-to-customize-logging-of-the-tsserver-iinstance-webstorm-is-using

Comment: Thanks for this, I was experiencing the same issue with WebStorm overriding the log file setting & its logs not actually showing the TS log contents. On Mac, `open -a "WebStorm.app"` in the terminal will open WebStorm while using this env var.